# LINQ To Entities cannot generate string MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, razor, linq-to-entities

When Using LINQ to get information I use the following method

```
var salt_water_disposals = _SaltWaterDisposals.SaltWaterDisposals.Select(sw => new SaltWaterModel
            {

                saltwater_ID = sw.SaltWaterDisposalID,
                lease = sw.Lease.LeaseName,
                field = sw.Lease.Field.Name.ToLower(),
                permitter_fluid = sw.PermittedFluids.Count == 0 ? "None" : sw.PermittedFluids.Aggregate("", (current, c) => current+c.Fluid.Name),
                max_gas_pressure = sw.MaxGasInjectionPressure,

            });
```

However when I run the code I get the following error because of the PermittedFluids:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Aggregate[PermittedFluid,String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[FieldPro.Domain.Entities.PermittedFluid],
>   System.String,
>   System.Func`3[System.String,FieldPro.Domain.Entities.PermittedFluid,System.String])'
>   method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

I have tried using it also as a ToString() but I get the same error.

Any Ideas?

Any Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by taking out the Aggregate call and calling it in my view, and changing the data type or permitter_fluid.

So My model has:

```
public System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<FieldPro.Domain.Entities.PermittedFluid> permitter_fluid { get; set; }
```

My Controller has:

```
permitter_fluid = sw.PermittedFluids,
```

and my view has (using a Html.Grid from MvCContrib):

```
column.For(m => m.permitter_fluid.Aggregate("", (current, c) => current + c.Fluid.Name)).Named("Permitted Fluid");
```

This solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

As you may know, LINQ translates your code into a SQL statement.  It can't translate all code, and this is one of those cases.

System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions is a class that has many static methods that are valid within the LINQ context.

Comment: I have used  SqlFunctions.StringConvert to convert a double to string, could it be used in a similar way to get LINQ to translate all the code? Or is there a similar function?